# problam wuth Uploading csv file

Tags: csv

I'm trying to upload a csv file to R and when I do its write this messege:
[image]

this is the scv file , Itried to upload the file, but I don't know if I can here,

[image]

Comment: I cant upload the pictures

Comment: What error code do you get? How does your csv file look like? Does it contain comments, separators?